# How can I compile a C# code if my project is split into several source files?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I wrote a simple two-class project in C# and as I would do in Java I split the classes into two separate source files. When I try to run the source file with main, the compiler does not find the other file. What should I include to make it work?

I have one file with the class main and another file with a class Foo.cs.
They are in the same namespace

Comment: You have to have a project file. Your project file must have both class files included in it.

Comment: Are they in the same namespace and directory?

Comment: Just specify all the files: `csc Foo.cs Bar.cs Baz.cs`. Although it would generally be better to create a project file and build that way...

Comment: They are in the same namespace and directory. Could you please provide a source with example of build with more source files? Thank you

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio? Are they visible in there? What is the exact error message?

Comment: For this I only used a text editor and compiled with csc.exe in cmd. It works as long as all classes are within one file.

Comment: Do what @JonSkeet suggested.

Comment: Ok thank you :) What is the reason for the minus vote? Can i improwe my answer somehow?

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote because the documentation for csc.exe tells you how to compile multiple source files which indicates a lack of research on your part.

Comment: Oh ok.. well I guess this is more a project file problem. If the project grew bigger, adding every source file to cmd would be very ineffective. What I did not know was the existence of a project file.

Comment: Why dont you just download Visual Studio Community edition? It's free. https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15

Comment: Or at least use .NET Core SDK: "dotnet new console", edit whatever you like, then "dotnet run"...

Comment: Thanks for the VS recommendarion. For simple exercises at the begining with a new language, I prefer terminal-like compilation to get a better feel about what IDE does later on. VS is probably a good idea.

Comment: VS is awesome, but in some cases you just want a quick IDE, SharpDevelop is a nice alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good start would be to use an IDE like Visual Studio (The community edition is free) and it can be downloaded from [Microsoft](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/).

1. Create a new solution and project
2. Import the files (for VS, right click --> Add --> Existing item.
3. Compile the solution with the IDE